# kendo angular dropdown setting a value programmatically

Tags: angular, html.dropdownlistfor, kendo-ui-angular2

Using kendo angular dropdown, 
I can set the data and default value, but for some reason setting the value later on from the available options does not work?

i have a basic data model of {id:x, value:y}.
what is the correct code to set the value after the dropdown was initialized?

using latest version of angular and kendo.

initializing the value with:

```
public areaModel: {id:number, value: string}
```

then I tried to set it with:

```
this.areaModel = {id: data.site.siteId, value: data.site.siteName}
```

the actual dropdown is:

```
<kendo-dropdownlist [data]="area" [(ngModel)]="areaModel" [textFIeld]="value" [valueField]="id"></kendo-dropdownlist>
```

do ignore typo errors since I'm typing this amnually - the code is in a closed system.

also, everything else is working' I can set the data, I can get the selected value.

Comment: you need to post at least the code you're using. Without it will be hard to help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct syntax should be:

```
<kendo-dropdownlist [data]="area" [(ngModel)]="areaModel" textField="value" valueField="id"></kendo-dropdownlist>
```

You can also set the value of any kind of Kendo dropdown with the value property. For example with the Kendo dropdownlist, it works like this:

```
<kendo-dropdownlist [data]='area' formControlName='area' [value]='area[0]'></kendo-dropdownlist>
```

Of course in this case you have to be sure that there is at least one element in your area array.

I guess you already looked into the documentation for value binding using dropdowns, but just in case, [here it is](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/dropdownlist/value-binding/).

Answer (score 0):

this.arrayname.find(x => x.value==api value)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are importing FormModule in the current module where your component is declared. Even after mapping `[(ngModel)]` the initial selection was not appearing in the UI until I imported FormModule.

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```